# Need to close the alert generated while opening a URL using AutoIT with selenium in python 3.6

Tags: selenium, autoit, python-3.6

Trying to access a url and while opening it, an alert will be generated and need to click on cancel tab/close the alert.Then only, it will be redirected to url. I used switch_to_alert() to achieve this. But, its not working.

Edit1: Based on the suggestion to use AutoIT, updated the script to run autoscript.exe file.

Code of AutoIT:

```
MouseMove ( 1012, 320 [, speed = 10] )   #position of the button to be clicked on the alert
MouseClick ( "$MOUSE_CLICK_LEFT" [, 1012, 320 [, clicks=1 [, speed = 10]]] )
```

compiled above code with CompileScript(x64) which generated .exe file.

Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser=webdriver.Chrome()
url='my-url'
browser.maximize_window()
browser.get(url)
browser.implicitly_wait(5)
exec(open("click.exe").read())  #running the generated auto.exe file
```

Error:

It did not work and terminating with below error.

```
     File "popup.py", line 16, in <module>
   exec(open("click.exe").read())
 File "C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
0920/150119.844:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(17788)] [.DisplayCompositor-000000000D86FDD0]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glCreateAndConsumeTextureCHROMIUM: invalid mailbox name
0920/150119.853:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(9798)] [.DisplayCompositor-000000000D86FDD0]RENDER WARNING: texture bound to texture unit 0 is not renderable. It maybe non-power-of-2 and have incompatible textur
 filtering.
   return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
nicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x90 in position 2: character maps to <undefined>
```

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qkpEh.png)

Comment: You need to use something like 'AutoIt' to deal with this.

Comment: How to use it to close the alert?

Comment: probably this can help you out - https://www.guru99.com/use-autoit-selenium.html

Comment: I downloaded the setup but don't know which methods to be used for closing that non-html alert. Do you know?

Answer (score 0):

Use explicit or implicit wait until element is present and then try to close Alert.

```
wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10)
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((locator)))
```

Comment: There is no alertIspresent() function in python. I implemented it like this, but it did not help.                                                                          browser.implicitly_wait(10)
try:
 alert=browser.switch_to_alert()
except NoAlertPresentException:
 print("No alert present")

Comment: use implicit wait and try

Comment: Ok let me check